# Rebinding Developer Console

Tags: team-fortress-2

I like to have the developer console, but whenever I play i have to turn it off because I keep hitting it mid-battle. Is there like a "toggle_console" command I can bind to a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind <KEY> toggleconsole`

If you are using a non-english keyboard layout you may have to adapt what you enter in console or your config (cfg) files.

For example `bind \ toggleconsole` will bind [section sign (§)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) on some European keyboards. If you use the Options menu you will see what your key presses are producing.

`unbind <KEY>` can be used to deactivate a bind.

[console](/questions/tagged/console)[bind](/questions/tagged/bind)[shortcut](/questions/tagged/shortcut)[team-fortress-2](/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2)

Comment: I was actually pretty close with toggle_console then.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. It's under Options-Keyboard-Toggle Developer Console. Default key is tilde.